# How to replace widgetArgs with editorArgs in Editor dgrid

Tags: dgrid

In dgrid 0.3 widgetArgs is replaced with editorArgs which can't be specified as function any more. I need to show options in combobox by querying at runtime from server. When editor gets created at that time I don't have options available. Earlier I used to specify widgetrArgs as function and with every dbclick editor gets created with option passed to constructor through widgetargs but now 0.3 onward editor will be created only once then how to refresh options at runtime.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a jsonrest store to your combobox. The store would populate the values as & when required.